# Gedit 3.8.3 in Ubuntu 13.10 Editor Width Issue

Tags: gedit

Not sure if I have a wrong setting or something, but seems like the editor width is larger than its container, and it is ignoring/hidding the overflow. If I make the window wider, like two horizontal desktops panels, then I can see the hidden part.
Same happens when a file is externally updated, it doesnt show the 'refresh' button.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Edit** > **Preferences** and make sure "Enable text wrapping" is checked. This will make it so that lines of text that are longer than what can be displayed on the screen are "wrapped", in other words, they will appear, in Gedit, to continue on a new line.